# Get User Agent In Laravel and Serve The User With The Correct domain

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, server-side, user-agent

I have a situation at hand. Got a domain covid19zim.online and recently developed a dedicated mobile web version to be served on m.covid19zim.online.

So my question is how to I get user agent and direct the user based on the device they are visiting the platform from.

Desktop users will be served with covid19zim.online and mobile users m.covid19zim.online

I found the following package https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect but its use case is not clearly articulated for my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#introduction) and check with `Browser::isMobile()` and `Browser::isDesktop()` to [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-external-domains) them to where you want.

Comment: @jewishmoses thanks it worked, how can i mark this a best reply

Comment: Yah, I would upvote that answer never seen the browser facade, and its not in official docs as far as I can see.

Comment: @KurtFriars true that